# object ReactiveMongoPlugin in package reactivemongo is deprecated: Use ReactiveMongoModule and ReactiveMongoApi

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to migrate my project from using `play2-reactivemongo` version `0.10.5.0.akka23` to using version `0.11.7.play23`. It is important to note that I'm using Play **2.3**.

The [documentation for Play 2.4](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/play2.html#play-24) says that I should use `ReactiveMongoModule` and `ReactiveMongoApi`, but `ReactiveMongoApi` is only available in version `0.11.7.play24`.
It doesn't say anything about how to use it with Play 2.3, so I assumed I was still supposed to use `ReactiveMongoPlugin`. However, I'm still getting deprecation warnings on the use of `ReactiveMongoPlugin`:

```
object ReactiveMongoPlugin in package reactivemongo is deprecated: Use ReactiveMongoModule and ReactiveMongoApi.
```

Is the deprecation warning incorrect for version `0.11.7.play23`, or is there another way of accessing the API?